# Extract words that starts with a certain character from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a string as shown below

```
var str = "This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00";
```

I need to get the word that start with "£";
Result should be "£15.00" "£19.00"
How do I do it in Javascript?

Comment: Use the `.match()` method with a regular expression.

Comment: i tried like this @nicael, str.indexOf('£'). I know it will return index of the string. Also i get the solution with .match().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method

```js
var str = "This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00";

// if `£` follows non-digit also then use
console.log(str.match(/£\S+/g));
// if `£` follows only number with fraction
console.log(str.match(/£(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.split()` to convert the string to an array and then create a new array using `.filter` with what you are looking for.

```js
var str = "This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00";

var r = str.split(" ").filter(function(n) {
  if(/£/.test(n)) return n;
});

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility with :

```
var myChar = '£';
var str = "This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00";
var myArray = str.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].charAt(0) == myChar) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using regex expressions, storing each identified word( in this case the price) in an array and then grabbing it when needed

```
var re = /(?:^|[ ])£([a-zA-Z]+)/gm;
var str = 'This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00';
var identifiedWords;

while ((identifiedWords = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (identifiedWords.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the "identifiedWords" variable.
// eg identifiedWords[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a RegEx:

```
let str = "This product price is £15.00 and old price is £19.00";
let res = str.match(/£[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?/g);
```

The result will be:

```
["£15.00", "£19.00"]
```

Short explanation:

This RegEx matches all words which start with a `£` sign, followed by minimum one to n digits..

```
£[0-9]+
```

..and optional have two decimal digits.

```
(.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

The `g` modifier cause a global search.